# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre @staticmethod y @classmethod en Python?

Tags: python

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una función decorada con @staticmethod y una decorada con @classmethod en una clase de Python? [1]

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Juan, ya que tanto pregunta como respueta son traduccines literales de una [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) del sitio en inglés, deberias mirarte [¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s) para adecuarte al concenso sobre este tema. Deberías  añadir un enlace a la pregunta y respuesta originales. Saludos.

Answer (score 9):

Lo explico con un ejemplo entre los métodos *foo*, *class_foo* y *static_foo*, en los dos últimos usando los decoradores:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self,x):
        print "ejecutando foo(%s,%s)"%(self,x)

    @classmethod
    def class_foo(cls,x):
        print "ejecutando class_foo(%s,%s)"%(cls,x)

    @staticmethod
    def static_foo(x):
        print "ejecutando static_foo(%s)"%x

a=A()
```

Con la forma usual de llamar los métodos; la instancia del objeto a, es implícitamente pasado como primer argumento:

```
a.foo(1)
# ejecutando foo(<__main__.A object at 0xb7dbef0c>,1)
```

Con los métodos de clase: *classmethods*, la clase de la instancia implícitamente es pasada como el primer argumento en lugar del *self*.

```
a.class_foo(1)
# ejecutando class_foo(<class '__main__.A'>,1)
```

Gracias a que no depende de la instancia, usted también puede llamar *class_foo* usando la clase. De hecho, si define un método para ser una *classmethod*, es mejor práctica el hacerlo en lugar de llamarla como una instancia para evitar confusiones. Si llama *A.foo(1)* le aparecerá un error *TypeError*, pero *A.class_foo(1)* funciona perfecto:

```
A.class_foo(1)
# ejecutando class_foo(<class '__main__.A'>,1)
```

Con *staticmethods*, ni el *self* (la instancia del objeto) ni *cls* (la clase) son implícitamente pasados como primer argumento. Son como funciones planas excepto que las puede llamar desde la clase o desde una instancia de la clase:

```
a.static_foo(1)
# ejecutando static_foo(1)

A.static_foo('hola')
# ejecutando static_foo(hola)
```

Los *staticmethods* son usados para agrupar métodos que tienen cierta relación lógica entre clases de la clase.

*foo* es solo una función, pero cuando usted llama *a.foo* no sólo obtiene la función, sino que obtiene una versión de la función con el la instancia del objeto como primer argumento de la función. *foo* requiere 2 argumentos, mientras que *a.foo* solamente requiere 1 argumento.

a está ligado a *foo*. Esto es lo que significa el término "bound" abajo:

```
print(a.foo)
# <bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0xb7d52f0c>>
```

Con *.class_foo*, *a* no está ligado *class_foo*, en su lugar la clase *A* es la que está ligada a *class_foo*:

```
print(a.class_foo)
# <bound method type.class_foo of <class '__main__.A'>>
```

Con *staticmethod*, aunque sea un método, *a.static_foo* solo retorna una función sin argumentos ligados. *static_foo* requiere 1 argumento, y *a.static_foo* requiere 1 argumento también:

```
print(a.static_foo)
# <function static_foo at 0xb7d479cc>
```

Y por supuesto lo mismo pasa cuando llama *static_foo* con la clase *A*:

```
print(A.static_foo)
# <function static_foo at 0xb7d479cc>
```

Ver original de la pregunta/respuesta en ingles [1].

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: Ver el original en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: Terrible traducción... "Los staticmethods son usados para agrupar funciones que tienen cierta relación lógica entre clases de la clase." . Las funciones que hay dentro de una clase no se llaman funciones, se llaman métodos. Y relación lógica entre clases de la clase?... no se entiende nada la traducción no solo de esto, sino en general.