# Cual es la forma correcta de hacer una clase en python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en el foro y estoy aprendiendo python, tengo unas dudas como por ejemplo como se debe de hacer correctamente una clase en python, hice una clase segun mis conocimientos en java pero me he dado cuenta que en python es diferente, aqui pongo el codigo de la clase de ejm Client que cree usando la metodologia del setter y getter similar a como se usa en java.

```
class Client:
# Constructor sobrecargado
def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, lastName=None, dni=None):
    self.__id = id
    self.__name = name
    self.__lastName = lastName
    self.__dni = dni

# Setter y Getter
def setId(self, id):
    self.__id = id

def getId(self):
    return self.__id

def setName(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def getName(self):
    return self.__name

def setLastName(self, lastName):
    self.__lastName = lastName

def getLastName(self):
    return self.__lastName

def setDni(self, dni):
    self.__dni = dni

def getDni(self):
    return self.__dni

# Metodos
def __str__(self):
    return f"Id: {self.__id :<3s} Name: {self.__name :<20s} LastName: {self.__lastName :<20s} DNI: {self.__dni :<20s}"

def showData(self):
    return "Name: {:<20s} LastName: {:<20s} DNI: {:<15s}".format(self.__name, self.__lastName, self.__dni)

"""Obtiene los datos del cliente para insertar en la tabla"""

def getDataUser(self):
    self.__name = input("Insert the name: ")
    self.__lastName = input("Insert the last name: ")
    self.__dni = input("Insert the dni: ")
```

Y aqui tambien pongo el mismo codigo pero siguiendo la metodologia de estilo que se usa en python, la verdad es bastante diferente y mi duda mas fuerte es cual deberia seguir usando ya que hasta ahora he probado las dos clase y ambas funcionan bien.

```
class Client:
# Constructor sobrecargado
def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, lastName=None, dni=None):
    self.__id = id
    self.__name = name
    self.__lastName = lastName
    self.__dni = dni

# Getter
@property
def id(self):
    return self.__id

@property
def name(self):
    return self.__name

@property
def lastName(self):
    return self.__lastName

@property
def dni(self):
    return self.__dni

# Setters
@id.setter
def id(self, id):
    self.__id = id

@name.setter
def name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

@lastName.setter
def lastName(self, lastName):
    self.__lastName = lastName

@dni.setter
def dni(self, dni):
    self.__dni = dni

# Metodos
def __str__(self):
    return f"Id: {self.__id :<3s} Name: {self.__name :<20s} LastName: {self.__lastName :<20s} DNI: {self.__dni :<20s}"

@classmethod
def showData(cls):
    return "Name: {:<20s} LastName: {:<20s} DNI: {:<15s}".format(cls.__name, cls.__lastName, cls.__dni)

"""Obtiene los datos del cliente para insertar en la tabla"""

@classmethod
def getDataUser(cls):
    cls.__name = input("Insert the name: ")
    cls.__lastName = input("Insert the last name: ")
    cls.__dni = input("Insert the dni: ")
```

Comment: En python no es necesario usar setters ni getters para acceder a una variable de clase, basta con escribir `mi_clase.mi_variable` y listo. Ni la he definido en un setter ni la estoy llamando con in getter, ni estoy usando propiedades.  EDIT: Esto quizá te ayude: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/property-getters-setters

Comment: Tal ves te sea útil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100909/31764

Comment: Gracias, habia cosas que no me quedaban claro, aunque como comenta en la pagina todo depende que lo que vaya a hacer, en mi caso necesito que los atributos esten encapsulados. muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que se te ha quitado la identacion al copiar y pegar, la clase en Python podría quedar tan simple como esto:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, lastName=None, dni=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dni = dni
```

De esta forma ahora podriamos **instanciar** la clase y consultar sus atributos.

```
clase_cliente = Client('12', 'Alberto', 'Rubiales', '3958923' )

In[5] clase_cliente.name
out[5]'Alberto'

In[6] clase_cliente.lastname
Out[6] 'Rubiales'
```

#### Añadiendo funcionalidades a la clase

Esto nos permite interactuar con el objeto y realizar cambios en él. Por ejemplo:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, lastName=None, dni=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dni = dni

    def change_id(self):
        self.id = input()

    @property
    def change_name(self):
        self.name = input()

    def change_lastname(self):
        self.lastName = input()

    def change_dni(self):
        self.dni = input()
```

De esta forma podemos ir introduciéndole o cambiándole sus atributos (es lo que hemos definido en las funciones) como nos plazca

```
clase_cliente = Client()

#como todo lo hemos instanciado con None, no nos devuelve nada
In[8] Clase cliente.dni


#Pero podemos introducirle información gracias a las funciones creadas
In[9] clase_cliente.change_dni()
>? d874852

#Y ahora volvemos a consultar y nos da lo que hemos introducido
In[10] clase_cliente.dni
Out[10] 'd874852'
```

#### Decorador property

Al fijar el decorador `@property`, nos permite ejecutar la función definida como si fuera un atributo

```
clase_cliente.change_name
>? Rodrigo

#Consultamos el cambio
In[11] clase_cliente.name
Out[11] Rodrigo
```

Sí quieres ver lo que hace `@classmethod` [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79446/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-staticmethod-y-classmethod-en-python) hay otra respuesta de la comunidad sobre ello.

Me podría extender indefinidamente hablando sobre clases y decoradores. Y aunque no tengo conocimientos de Java, como puedes ver la principal diferencia es que no hacen falta ni getters ni setters y la estructura y sintaxis es más corta.

Comment: Gracias, segun lo que ya sabia estaba programando como lo lo hacia lo java, aunque me doy cuenta que si hay mucha diferencia. No me queda uy claro lo del @classmethod entiendo que si instancio una clase y le paso datos y si llamo al metodo con este decorador este ultimo dato sera diferente a los que se pasaron por el constructor de la clase.