# Falta un argumento a la hora de llamar una función de una clase abstracta Python

Tags: python, clase-abstracta, self, missings

Estoy intentando organizar mi código, hice una clase abstracta para poder mandarla llamar y realizar un envío de información sin la necesidad de estar llamando a conectar el dispositivo cada vez que lo necesite.

```
class CANMsgs:
    CANDll_ = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        global CANDll_
        CANDll_ = CANCommunicationDll()    


class AMECommands(ABC, CANMsgs):

    WRITE_BYTE = "0x7D0"
    startEol = "2E FD 00 80 01"

    @abstractmethod
    def LogFolder(self):
        if os.path.exists("C:\\temp"):
            shutil.rmtree("C:\\temp")
            os.mkdir("C:\\temp")
        else:
            os.mkdir("C:\\temp")

    @abstractmethod
    def Start(self):
        CANMsgs()
        AMECommands.LogFolder()

    @abstractmethod
    def SendMessage(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.WRITE_BYTE = AMECommands.WRITE_BYTE
        self.startEol = AMECommands.startEol

        CANDll_.Commands.ConnectCANDevice()
        CANDll_.Commands.SendMessage(self.WRITE_BYTE, self.startEol)
        CANDll_.Commands.SendMessage(self.WRITE_BYTE, self.cmd)
        CANDll_.Commands.DisconnectCANDevice()
```

Y aquí es como la mando llamar en otro archivo

```
AMECommands.Start()
AMECommands.SendMessage("2E FD 00 84 43 02 01 01")
```

Pero me manda este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\PythonProjects\KeyboardSubaruCANMessages\kscm.py", line 
67, in <module>
AMECommands.Start()
TypeError: AMECommands.Start() missing 1 required positional 
argument: 'self'
```

Pero yo no estoy enviando nada como argumento y no espero que se envíe nada, no se si es porque estoy usando una clase abstracta, y siendo así como tendría que llamar adecuadamente ese método de la clase abstracta.

Comment: La funcion def Start(self) tambien tiene arriba @abstractmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la verdad que viendo el problema y el código no se muy bien que pretendes hacer.

Lo que si puedo comentarte es, que no puedes llamar al método de la clase de forma directa si no has creado instancia de dicha clase. Esto es debido a que creas la función con primer parámetro "self", indicándole su pertenencia a esta.

Por tanto, si lo que quieres llamar la función de esa forma "estática" (como se llamaría en otros lenguajes), tienes 2 opciones:

- Quitar el "self" de la definición.
- Añadir el decorador @classmethod.

Comment: He encontrado esta respuesta que lo explica de una forma bastante completa:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79448